# Regex to check only one integer

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to work with a Regex in order to check if a given string contains a single integer value (and possibly spaces - including tabs, line feeds... - at both ends)

I have this so far `var reg = /^\d+$/;` but as I see this works only for numbers.

```
var reg = /^\d+$/;

function myFn(str) {

}
```

what am I missing?

Comment: What you're missing is a basic understanding of regexp. If you want to allow optional spaces at the beginning, then put optional spaces at that point in the regexp, and similarly for the end.

Comment: Is there a possibility for a negative integer?

Comment: @AlexW umm no, actually all I see in the info talks about an integer, can't see the word negative anywhere.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer I guess you should be aware that an integer can inherently be negative and that your regex does not account for those possibilities.  It may not be applicable to your use case but it's something to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

```
js> /^\s*\d+\s*$/.test(" 89 ")
true
```